# Roman chapter numbers cause overfull hbox in titletoc-ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, titletoc, roman-numerals

`Overfull hbox` in ToC after chapter numbers changed to `Roman`; see MWE below. With the `tocloft` package `\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{3em}` solves the problem.

**But**: Is there any solution to the problem *NOT* using `tocloft` but `titletoc`?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lipsum}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Introduction to introduction}
\subsubsection{Introduction to introduction to introduction}
\end{document}
```

PS: I have specified certain things in the ToC using `titletoc` and would be glad not to have to do everything again with `tocloft`. That's why I want to avoid the `tocloft` solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an adaption of Philippe Goudet's anwer where the horizontal alignment of the various ToC entries resembles that of the standard classes:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[3em]{\addvspace{10pt}\bfseries}
    {\contentslabel{2.5em}}{\hspace{-2.5em}}{\hfill\contentspage}
\dottedcontents{section}[6.3em]{}{3.3em}{0.7pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[10.5em]{}{4.2em}{0.7pc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\chapter{Lipsum}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Introduction to introduction}
\subsubsection{Introduction to introduction to introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you both! That's what I was looking for. What's your personal/subjective opinion: In Philippe Goudet's solution the horizontal alignment is somewhat irritating. In lockstep's solution this is better but my impression is that things get too much "stretched". So I cannot decide which solutions looks more professional. Or should I perhaps better stick to the arabic numbers which avoids both of the before mentioned problems? A personal recommendation would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: In my opinion, a large indentation of subsections is less irritating than non-aligned entries. Personally, I'd either use arabic numbering or exclude subsections from the ToC (`\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`).

Answer (score 9):

You can fully personalize the entries with [titletoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) by using `\titlecontents`. For each section level, you need to change the left indent and the `\contentslabel` by choosing an appropriate value:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\titlecontents{chapter}%
  [3em]% left indent
  {\addvspace{1em plus 0pt}\bfseries}% stuff before
  {\contentslabel{3em}}% before if there's a number
  {\hspace{-3em}}% before if there's no number
  {\hfill\contentspage}% dots and page number
  [\addvspace{0pt}]% stuff after

\dottedcontents{section}%
  [5em]% left indent
  {\addvspace{0pt}}% stuff before
  {3.5em}% spacing of \contentslabel
  {0.75em}% space between the dots
  [\addvspace{0pt}]% stuff after

\dottedcontents{subsection}%
  [7.5em]% left indent
  {\addvspace{0pt}}% stuff before
  {4.25em}% spacing of \contentslabel
  {0.75em}% space between the dots
  [\addvspace{0pt}]% stuff after

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\chapter{Lipsum}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Introduction to introduction}
\subsubsection{Introduction to introduction to introduction}

\end{document}
```