# Label appendix as Appendix I, II, III rather than Appendix A, B and C

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

When I am using the `\appendix` it is automatically naming the Appendix as Appendix A, A.1, A.2 etc.

Is there a way to change it to Appendix I, I.1, I.2, II.1, etc?

here is my current appendix commands:

```
\appendix
\include{AppendixA}
\cleardoublepage
\include{AppendixB}
\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: the code to change the appendix (= chapter) number is in the question [Roman chapter numbers cause overfull hbox in titletoc-ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66289/), which may have some other useful information when the width of the numbers expands beyond preset limits.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on your document class. If it has `\chapter`s, then you can use

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

otherwise (if it the highest sectional unit is `\section`), use

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
```

*after* `\appendix`. Combining this into the document preamble (not a bad thing), you could use

```
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \oldappendix%
  \renewcommand{\the<unit>}{\Roman{<unit>}}}%
```

where `<unit>` defines the highest section unit in your class (say `chapter` or `section`).

Comment: In case anyone would prefer arabic numerals (1,2,3,..), the command is unsurprisingly `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}` (but not "Arabic").

Answer (score 1):

With the standard LaTeX classes, KoMa-script ones and also `memoir`, the definition can be patched quite safely (before `hyperref`, if this package is loaded):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\appendix}{\@Alph}{\@Roman}
  {}{\@latex@warning@no@line{\protect\appendix\space couldn't be patched}
\makeatletter
```

If the patch is not successful, which LaTeX will warn you about, it may be because the class already loads `hyperref` (which is not recommended, actually); in that case, try

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\HyOrg@appendix}{\@Alph}{\@Roman}
  {}{\@latex@warning@no@line{\protect\appendix\space couldn't be patched}
\makeatletter
```

because this is the "original" command as saved by `hyperref`.