# Separate toc for appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, article

I am struggeling with creating a seperate toc for my appendix.

This is what I currently have:

> Contents
>   1 first section......1
>   2 second section.....2
>   List of appendices...5

This is what I'd like to achieve:

> Contents
>   1 first section......1
>   2 second section.....2
>   List of appendices...5

**plus** a seperate toc for my appendix including all sections:

> List of appendices
>   I My first appendix......5
>   II My second appendix.....6

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

% as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100479/label-appendix-as-appendix-i-ii-iii-rather-than-appendix-a-b-and-c
\let\oldappendix\appendices
\renewcommand{\appendices}{%
  \clearpage
  \oldappendix
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
  }%

% use custom names for appendices
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{List of appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{List of appendices}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{first section}
\lipsum
\section{second section}
\lipsum

\begin{appendices}
    \section{My first appendix}
    \lipsum
    \section{My second appendix}
    \lipsum
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Your help is highly appreciated. I've tried solving my issue with `minitoc`, however I couldn't achieve what I exactly wanted. I really apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find answers for my specific problem.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `etoc` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The separate `Toc` for the appendix entries can be achieved by letting an `.app` (for example) file handle point to `.toc`, i.e. at a certain point of document stopping to write to the `.toc` file and everything meant for the `.toc` enters the `.app` file.

I have defined a  `\listofappendices` macro, that reuses `\tableofcontents` by renaming `\contentsname` and applying `\@starttoc{app}` instead of `\@starttoc{toc}`.

Please note, that any writting attempt to the `.toc` will finally be placed in the `.app` file, so if this is not desired, the file handle must be restored at the end of `appendices`; this is not yet done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Not needed since TL 2018
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}


% as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100479/label-appendix-as-appendix-i-ii-iii-rather-than-appendix-a-b-and-c

% use custom names for appendices

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{List of appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendices}

\makeatletter
\let\oldappendix\appendices

\renewcommand{\appendices}{%
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
  % From now, everything goes to the app - file and not to the toc
  \let\tf@toc\tf@app
  \addtocontents{app}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@app^^J
  }
  \oldappendix
}%



\newcommand{\listofappendices}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\appendixtocname}
  \let\@oldstarttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{\@oldstarttoc{app}}
  \tableofcontents% Reusing the code for \tableofcontents with different \contentsname and different file handle app
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listofappendices



\section{first section}
\lipsum
\section{second section}
\lipsum

\section{Third section}
\lipsum




\begin{appendices}
    \section{My first appendix}
    \lipsum
    \section{My second appendix}
    \lipsum

    \section{My third appendix}
    \lipsum

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

**Update** Version with restoring the possibility to write to the original ToC after the appendices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Not needed since TL 2018
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100479/label-appendix-as-appendix-i-ii-iii-rather-than-appendix-a-b-and-c

% use custom names for appendices

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{List of appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendices}

\makeatletter
\let\oldappendix\appendices

\g@addto@macro\tableofcontents{%
  % Store the current toc file for later usage
  \let\tf@toc@orig\tf@toc
}
\renewcommand{\appendices}{%
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
  % From now, everything goes to the app - file and not to the toc
  \let\tf@toc\tf@app
  \addtocontents{app}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@app
  }
  \oldappendix
}%

\g@addto@macro\endappendices{%
  % Switch back to the old toc file handle
  \let\tf@toc\tf@toc@orig
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@toc@orig
  }%
}  

\newcommand{\listofappendices}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\appendixtocname}
  \let\@oldstarttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{\@oldstarttoc{app}}
  \tableofcontents% Reusing the code for \tableofcontents with different \contentsname and different file handle app
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listofappendices



\section{first section}
\lipsum
\section{second section}
\lipsum

\section{Third section}
\lipsum




\begin{appendices}
    \section{My first appendix}
    \lipsum
    \section{My second appendix}
    \lipsum

    \section{My third appendix}
    \lipsum

\end{appendices}

\section{A section after the appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian for your efforts. Does what it is supposed to do!

Comment: @KarelZe: Happy Texing!